# Is this searching algorithm optimal?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, optimization, search

I have two lists, L and M, each containing thousands of 64-bit unsigned integers. I need to find out whether the sum of any two members of L is itself a member of M.

Is it possible to improve upon the performance of the following algorithm?

```
Sort(M)
for i = 0 to Length(L)
    for j = i + 1 to Length(L)
        BinarySearch(M, L[i] + L[j])
```

Comment: Can you stop once you find one example?  If so, that's important, but it's not super-clear from the phrasing of the question if it's allowed.  Also, putting M into a hash table will give asymptotically faster results than using binary search.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear - no, the search cannot stop once it finds a single match.

Comment: If you do pre-process the M list (either to sort it or put it in a hashmap) maybe you could store the highest value in M and skip elements of L which are larger than max(M)?

Comment: Are the lists already sorted?

Comment: @Tom Anderson: almost certainly not since the code snippet in the question shows him sorting one of the inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm assuming your goal is to find *all* pairs in L that sum to something in M)

Forget hashtables!

Sort both lists.

Then do the outer loop of your algorithm: walk over every element i in L, then every larger element j in L. As you go, form the sum and check to see if it's in M.

But don't look using a binary search: simply do a linear scan from the last place you looked. Let's say you're working on some value i, and you have some value j, followed by some value j'. When searching for (i+j), you would have got to the point in M where that value is found, or the first largest value. You're now looking for (i+j'); since j' > j, you know that (i+j') > (i+j), and so it cannot be any earlier in M than the last place you got. If L and M are both smoothly distributed, there is an excellent chance that the point in M where you would find (i+j') is only a little way off.

If the arrays are not smoothly distributed, then better than a linear scan might be some sort of jumping scan - look forward N elements at a time, halving N if the jump goes too far.

I believe this algorithm is O(n^2), which is as fast as any proposed hash algorithm (which have an O(1) primitive operation, but still have to do O(n**2) of them. It also means that you don't have to worry about the O(n log n) to sort. It has much better data locality than the hash algorithms - it basically consists of paired streamed reads over the arrays, repeated n times.

---

EDIT: I have written implementations of Paul Baker's original algorithm, Nick Larsen's hashtable algorithm, and my algorithm, and a simple benchmarking framework. The implementations are simple (linear probing in the hashtable, no skipping in my linear search), and i had to make guesses at various sizing parameters. See http://urchin.earth.li/~twic/Code/SumTest/ for the code. I welcome corrections or suggestions, about any of the implementations, the framework, and the parameters.

For L and M containing 3438 items each, with values ranging from 1 to 34380, and with Larsen's hashtable having a load factor of 0.75, the median times for a run are:

- Baker (binary search): 423 716 646 ns
- Larsen (hashtable): 733 479 121 ns
- Anderson (linear search): 62 077 597 ns

The difference is much bigger than i had expected (and, i admit, not in the direction i had expected). I suspect i have made one or more major mistakes in the implementation. If anyone spots one, i really would like to hear about it!

One thing is that i have allocated Larsen's hashtable inside the timed method. It is thus paying the cost of allocation and (some) garbage collection. I think this is fair, because it's a temporary structure only needed by the algorithm. If you think it's something that could be reused, it would be simple enough to move it into an instance field and allocate it only once (and Arrays.fill it with zero inside the timed method), and see how that affects performance.

Comment: Your lookup in `M` has a minimum of 1 lookup per `L^2`, while a hash set of `M` has exactly 1 lookup, regardless of where it is in the set.  Also your answer implies different implementations depending on the distribution of input, which is unknown to the algorithm.

Comment: Number of lookups: I don't think any one pass over L in the inner loop will make more than |M| lookups in M - how could it? Assuming all pairs from L are inside the range covered by M, that means the total number of lookups will be at most |L| * |M|. A hashtable will make exactly |L|^2. I'm hoping that my lookups will be faster due to locality - although considering the small size of the dataset ("thousands"), it will probably all fit in cache anyway.

Comment: Distribution: "different implementations" - how do you mean? You mean skipping vs not? I would imagine the implementer, knowing more about the problem, would be able to make a good guess as to whether skipping or some other trick would be useful. But if not, it could be decided adaptively. I'm thinking of a somewhat similar skipping ("galloping"?) behaviour in Timsort that does this.

Comment: @Tom: Number of lookups: if I understand your idea correctly, you hold a pointer in M and walkthrough it for each L0 + L1, meaning you have at least 1 lookup in M for each of L^2 lookups.  A hash set has exactly 1 lookup in M for each of L1 + L2.

Comment: @Tom: Distribution: I agree there can be improvements made with more information about the input, however, we have no indication from the question that there is knowledge of it.  It's a good answer, just to a question that hasn't been asked.

Comment: @Nick when looking for i+j, Tom may find that the lookup in M (call it m) is bigger than i+j. The next thing to do when looking for i'+j' is to check to see if m is bigger than i'+j'. If it is, then we have handled that pair without any lookups (because we can remember the value). Nick's array case requires a variable number of lookups in M, but it will be no more than 1 on average, and can be lower.

Comment: @Nick: I've written code and reported benchmarks. I would appreciate it if you could tell me if i've screwed up the implementation of your algorithm.

Comment: @Tom Good work on setting up a test.  I'll look over it and get back to you later tonight.

Comment: @Tom: your implementation of a hash set is unnecessary, Java has one built in.  Other than that, I don't like your decision to choose less than random numbers.  The question makes no limitations on the values and it's actually a much easier implementation without the extra stuff.  Also, it's fair to do the allocation inside the timer because it is necessary.  It is also fair to use the same truncation technique in my implementation as you use in yours.

Comment: @Tom: in my c# implementation, I have found that c# can access an array index much faster than calling hashset.contains(). This made your impl faster. This prompted me to put your search into it's own function called search (or I could have just as easily implemented my own hash set in my function).  After that, every time mine was faster by the time it takes to build the hash set vs sort the arrays.  Then I realized all of these are implementation details and we could do this all day back and forth.  The question is `[language-agnostic]` though, which means only asymptotic analysis is useful.

Comment: @Nick: i wrote my own because i knew that it would be much faster than Java's general-purpose hashset, and it's easy enough to do. As you saw, it's also faster in C# - and it's even worse in Java, because Java has more rudimentary handling of primitive types like longs in generic collections. Sorry about the slightly iffy number generation, but the correct algorithm is a pain to implement, and i doubted it would make a significant difference.

Comment: @Nick: could you expand on what you mean by "put your search into it's own function called search"?

Comment: @Tom: I used the built in hash set in c# and later java, both cases build predictably faster than sorting an array even with the memory allocation. The work in both functions is done after the sum is complete, up to that point they are identical implementations. The work function is M.contains(sum), which I check through a method on the hash set. You implement it inline, avoiding the cost of the function call, so I extracted your inline solution to it's own method (or I could have written my own inline hash set impl).

Comment: @Tom the last note, your hash set impl is a hash table and has a search time of O(n), which should be edited to be constant time.

Comment: @Nick: Um, i don't believe it is O(n). Are you mistaking the linear probing for a linear scan? I still don't understand the distinction you make between hash sets and hash tables.

Comment: @Tom: again, a hash set has exactly 1 value for each hash, a hash table has a bucket of all values for each hash. In a hash set, only the first value for a particular hash gets saved, attempts to enter a second value for a given hash fail. The cointains impl then simply takes the value at the hash, no iteration necessary. It is easy to generate thousands of unique values for your impl which all have the same hash, which would require exactly O(n) search time.

Comment: @Nick: So how does your idea of a hash set deal with two different values which hash to the same location in the set? Can i construct the hash set or not?

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of the example code in the question is O(m log m + l<sup>2</sup> log m) where l=|L| and m=|M| as it runs binary search (O(log m)) for every pair of elements in L (O(l<sup>2</sup>)), and M is sorted first.

Replacing the binary search with a hash table reduces the complexity to O(l<sup>2</sup>) assuming that hash table insert and lookup are O(1) operations.

This is asymptotically optimal as long as you assume that you need to process every pair of numbers on the list L, as there are O(l<sup>2</sup>) such pairs. If there are a couple of thousands of numbers on L, and they are random 64-bit integers, then definitely you need to process all the pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting `M` at a cost of `n * log(n)`, you could create a hash set at the cost of `n`.

You could also store all sums in another hash set while iterating and add a check to make sure you don't perform the same search twice.

Comment: Note: I do mean hash set, not hash table.

Comment: I understand 'hash set' to mean 'a set implemented with a hash table'. What do you mean by the two terms?

Comment: A hash set is often used as a "has been visited" concept, and only 1 value can exist for each hash value.  In a hash table, the hash value represents a bucket filled with all the items that have that hash value.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid binary search by using hashtable except sorted M array.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, add all of the members of L to a hashset lSet, then iterate over M, performing these steps for each m in M:

1. add m to hashset mSet - if m is already in mSet, skip this iteration; if m is in hashset dSet, also skip this iteration.
2. subtract each member l of L less than m from m to give d, and test whether d is also in lSet;
3. if so, add (l, d) to some collection rSet; add d to hashset dSet.

This will require fewer iterations, at the cost of more memory. You will want to pre-allocate the memory for the structures, if this is to give you a speed increase.